# What's wrong with the SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (customer_id TEXT NOT NULL, time_stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, customer_info TEXT), PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp)`

The error is

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (customer_id TEXT NOT NULL, time_stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        customer_info TEXT), PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
                     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
                      near ' PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp)' at line 1
```

Comment: is that comma before `PRIMARY KEY` neccessary? By the way, a time stamp doesn't seem like a good PK for a customer. Shouldn't it be `customer_id`?

Comment: +1 Thanks for catching a copy/paste bug :-)  Customer ID should indeed be the primary key.  If you hadn't told me, I would have to have awarded you the answer to my next question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary key column needs to be defined within the `CREATE TABLE` parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
  customer_id TEXT NOT NULL, 
  time_stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  customer_info TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (time_stamp)
)
```

I'm curious why you didn't make `customer_id` an indexable data type and therefore the primary key column...

Comment: @Mawg: Yup, it's to give others with different answers a chance to chip in.

Comment: I see (+1). I never had an answer in under 10 minutes before :-)